# Sql query lag running calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have came across a strange requirement where I need to compute running calculation in database query

I have one table 
Table A:

```
Day     QTY 
0       NULL    
1       1       
2       1       
3       0       
4       0       
5       2       
6       1       
7       1       
8       3
```

using this table I need to calculate other columns

```
Day QTY     Op_Qty  CL_QTY  Reqd        Need    Adjust
0   0       null        3   -           -        -
1   1       3           2   -           -        -
2   1       2           1   Reqd        3        -
3   0       1           1   Reqd        3        -
4   0       1           4               0        3
5   2       4           5               0        3
6   1       5           4               0        0
7   1       4           3               0        0
8   3       3           0   Reqd        4        0

Logic :
CL_Qty starting value is 3 2nd row onwards its op_qty-qty+adjust
op_qty = previous record of cl_qty
reqd --> will start after 2 records and computation formula = if cl_qty is less than 2 then "reqd" else empty string
need --> will start after 2 records and computation formula = if reqd column value = "reqd" then (4- cl_qty) else 0
adjust --> will start after 4th record = 1st value of need
```

I have tried to use lag but nowhere closure to the result . It will be of great help with any input

Comment: provide the SQL

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Something is wrong in the requirements. What do you mean by "will start after 4th record"? Perhaps you meant to have 0 for the first three rows, but you show NULL. Which means the result for CL_Qty will be NULL for rows 2, 3, 4. Please clarify.

Comment: @mathguy We can set the first 3 rows as zero 0 . I have modified the output

Comment: What version of Oracle? If I am reading this correctly, "closing quantity" after several days depends on the "closing quantity" four days earlier, so you will need some sort of recursion. Recursive subquery factoring would solve the problem, but is available only in Oracle 11.2 and higher.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the input .I am using 11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mathguy pointed out, recursive ctes would allow for doing this inline.  As that isn't available here, and if your situation allows using `pl/sql` 
 (I couldn't quite tell from your post) perhaps it would be worth considering dropping into `pl/sql` and procedurally evaluating the dataset.

It may still be possible without resorting to `pl/sql` but without recursive subfactors, the mixed intra-row and inter-row relationships between attributes seemed less promising. This isn't pretty, but here's an example of generating your expected output given in your post with a function.

There are some caveats in this example:

- Oracle doesn't recognize empty strings, as you indicated should be
  present in `REQD` when not `'reqd'`.  I've used `NULL` here instead.
- As the value of `ADJUST` is used in calculating `CL_QTY`, `NULL` is not valid. For the first four records, `CL_QTY` uses a fixed `ADJUST` of `0`
  instead of the displayed `NULL`.  I'd recommend explicitly using `0`
  for the first four values of `ADJUST` instead of `NULL`.
- I was not sure here what is meant by *"1st value of need"* in the
  requirement that *"adjust --> will start after 4th record = 1st value
  of need"*.  In this example I took it to mean *"the last value of
  `NEED` that  hasn't already been used in `ADJUST` (2 records prior)"*
- This example presumes the row-level conditions should be deterministic and sorts by `DAY`.  If the sort order should be different, the cursor would need to be updated.

With that being said, here's an example of one approach you can use to reproduce the desired data table you presented is using a `function`:

First create the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE DAY_QUANTITY(
  DAY NUMBER,
  QTY NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (0,NULL);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (3,0);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (4,0);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (6,1);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (7,1);
INSERT INTO DAY_QUANTITY VALUES (8,3);
```

Then the `TYPE` to return:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE QTY_ADJUST_REC IS OBJECT(DAY NUMBER, QTY NUMBER, OP_QTY NUMBER, CL_QTY NUMBER, REQD VARCHAR2(10), NEED NUMBER, ADJUST NUMBER);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE QTY_ADJUST_TAB IS TABLE OF QTY_ADJUST_REC;
/
```

And the `FUNCTION`.  This will iterate through the data and apply the rules as they become eligible:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QTY_ADJUST
  RETURN QTY_ADJUST_TAB
IS
  V_ITERATION_COUNT NUMBER := 0;
  V_CL_QTY          NUMBER := 3;
  V_NEED            NUMBER := NULL;
  V_OP_QTY          NUMBER := NULL;
  V_REQD            VARCHAR2(10) := NULL;
  V_ADJUST          NUMBER := NULL;

  V_QTY_ADJUST_REC  QTY_ADJUST_REC;
  V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB  QTY_ADJUST_TAB;
  BEGIN
    V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB := QTY_ADJUST_TAB();

    FOR POINTER IN (SELECT
                      DAY,
                      QTY
                    FROM DAY_QUANTITY
                    ORDER BY DAY ASC)
    LOOP
      V_ITERATION_COUNT := V_ITERATION_COUNT + 1;

      IF V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.COUNT() > 0
      THEN
        V_OP_QTY := V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB(V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.COUNT()).CL_QTY;
        V_CL_QTY := (V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB(V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.COUNT()).CL_QTY
                     - POINTER.QTY
                     + CASE WHEN V_ITERATION_COUNT < 5 THEN 0 ELSE
          COALESCE(V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB(V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.COUNT() - 1).NEED, 0) END);
      END IF;

      IF V_ITERATION_COUNT > 2
      THEN
        V_REQD := CASE WHEN V_CL_QTY < 2
          THEN 'reqd'
                  ELSE NULL END;
        V_NEED := CASE WHEN V_CL_QTY < 2
          THEN (4 - V_CL_QTY)
                  ELSE 0 END;
      END IF;
      IF V_ITERATION_COUNT > 4
      THEN
        V_ADJUST := V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB(V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.COUNT() - 1).NEED;
      END IF;
      V_QTY_ADJUST_REC := QTY_ADJUST_REC(POINTER.DAY, POINTER.QTY, V_OP_QTY, V_CL_QTY, V_REQD, V_NEED, V_ADJUST);

      V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.EXTEND();
      V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB(V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB.COUNT()) := V_QTY_ADJUST_REC;

      V_CL_QTY := NULL;
      V_REQD := NULL;
      V_NEED := NULL;
      V_ADJUST := NULL;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN V_QTY_ADJUST_TAB;

  END;
/

Function QTY_ADJUST compiled
```

Then test it:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(QTY_ADJUST()) ORDER BY 1 ASC;

DAY  QTY  OP_QTY  CL_QTY  REQD  NEED  ADJUST  
0                 3                           
1    1    3       2                           
2    1    2       1       reqd  3             
3    0    1       1       reqd  3             
4    0    1       4             0     3       
5    2    4       5             0     3       
6    1    5       4             0     0       
7    1    4       3             0     0       
8    3    3       0       reqd  4     0
```

**EDIT: In response to your request for an additional subfactoring solution, here's an alternative example using a recursive CTE.**
This is mechanically similar to the procedural approach above--it builds the result set iteratively--but is SQL instead.

This example could do with some refactoring, but hopefully gives an example of one way recursive subfactoring can work (Please note there are other ways of generating this kind of data, and of using this type of query).

Using the same `DAY_QUANTITY` table and data from the above `PL/SQL` example, here's an example of a subfactor to apply the same processing to the data:

```
WITH NUMBERED_DAY_QTY(DAY, QTY, NUMBERED_ROW) AS (
   SELECT
     DAY_QUANTITY.DAY,
     DAY_QUANTITY.QTY,
     ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER (
       PARTITION BY NULL
       ORDER BY DAY_QUANTITY.DAY ASC ) - 1 AS NUMBERED_ROW
   FROM DAY_QUANTITY),
    DAY_QTY_ITER(DAY, QTY, NUMBERED_ROW, OP_QTY, CL_QTY, REQD, NEED, ADJUST, NEED_POINTER, ITERATION_LEVEL)
  AS (
    SELECT
      DAY,
      QTY,
      NUMBERED_ROW,
      CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) AS OP_QTY,
      3                    AS CL_QTY,
      NULL                 AS REQD,
      CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) AS NEED,
      CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) AS ADJUST,
      CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) AS NEED_POINTER,
      1                    AS ITERATION_LEVEL
    FROM NUMBERED_DAY_QTY
    WHERE DAY = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.DAY,
      NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.QTY,
      NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.NUMBERED_ROW,
      DAY_QTY_ITER.CL_QTY                               AS OP_QTY,
      (DAY_QTY_ITER.CL_QTY - NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.QTY +
       CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 4
         THEN 0
       ELSE COALESCE(DAY_QTY_ITER.NEED_POINTER, 0) END) AS CL_QTY,
      CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 2
        THEN NULL
      ELSE CASE WHEN (DAY_QTY_ITER.CL_QTY - NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.QTY +
                      CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 4
                        THEN 0
                      ELSE COALESCE(DAY_QTY_ITER.NEED_POINTER, 0) END) < 2
        THEN 'reqd'
           ELSE NULL END END                         AS REQD,
      CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 2
        THEN NULL
      ELSE CASE WHEN (DAY_QTY_ITER.CL_QTY - NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.QTY +
                      CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 4
                        THEN 0
                      ELSE COALESCE(DAY_QTY_ITER.NEED_POINTER, 0) END) < 2
        THEN (4 - (DAY_QTY_ITER.CL_QTY - NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.QTY +
                   CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 4
                     THEN 0
                   ELSE COALESCE(DAY_QTY_ITER.NEED_POINTER, 0) END))
           ELSE 0 END END                            AS NEED,
      CASE WHEN DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL < 4
        THEN NULL
      ELSE
        COALESCE(DAY_QTY_ITER.NEED_POINTER, 0) END      AS ADJUST,
      DAY_QTY_ITER.NEED                                 AS NEED_POINTER,
      DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL + 1                  AS ITERATION_LEVEL
    FROM NUMBERED_DAY_QTY
      INNER JOIN DAY_QTY_ITER ON NUMBERED_DAY_QTY.NUMBERED_ROW = DAY_QTY_ITER.ITERATION_LEVEL )
SELECT
  DAY, QTY, OP_QTY, CL_QTY, REQD, NEED, ADJUST
FROM DAY_QTY_ITER
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Then test it:

```
DAY  QTY  OP_QTY  CL_QTY  REQD  NEED  ADJUST  
0                 3                           
1    1    3       2                           
2    1    2       1       reqd  3             
3    0    1       1       reqd  3             
4    0    1       4             0     3       
5    2    4       5             0     3       
6    1    5       4             0     0       
7    1    4       3             0     0       
8    3    3       0       reqd  4     0       


9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the innovative solution, How to perform using recursion in 11.2

Comment: Thanks @luminita you'd like to see an SQL alternative?  Sure thing. I'm away from my desk but I'll post up an example when I'm back at my desk. I'll follow up when the update is posted. Thanks

Comment: @luminita I added another example using subfactoring to apply the same rules in sql only.  Is this the kind of thing you were hoping to see?  Thanks

Comment: you are great.I know it will take a time to digest.